# Trouble with react final form FieldArray, listeners and displaying data from api call outside of form

Tags: react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I want to trigger an API call to fetch some supplemental data and display it alongside my react final form. What's the best way to do this?

I've started by using `OnChange` from react-final-form-listeners to listen for a field change and make an API call, but I don't really know how to store this data somewhere and display it within the react-final-form framework. Using a functional component and a State hook, it would be relatively trivial, because I would just set the state of a variable and then display it somewhere in the same component. Is this a sign that I should be storing these kinds of things in redux? Can I use hooks instead?

I forked one of the examples and added what I am trying to do:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-field-arrays-k9pqm

Answer (score 0):

You're talking a little too abstractly about your goal here, but sure, you could keep the loaded data in state with a `useState()` hook. If I were you, I'd want to debounce it, and keep track of whether or not the Promise from your API call was the Promise from the last call or not.

Comment: Hi Erik. Could you please take a look at my recent questions in react-final-form? (Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873480/clear-a-fields-value-on-input-clear-in-react-final-form and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901348/how-to-implement-a-custom-component-with-two-values-in-react-final-form.) I'm really looking forward to your replies 