# Clear a field's value on input clear in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm using a custom component with `react-final-form`. On input change it sets the value to the `address` field. But when the input is cleared it doesn't update the value of the field. So I'm trying to do it with form mutators.

I have already added a mutator for clearing the field:

```
mutators={{
  clear: ([address], state, { changeValue }) => {
    changeValue(state, "address", () => undefined);
  }
}}
```

I tried to add it to my custom onChange function, but it doesn't work.

```
onChange={event =>
  props.input.onChange !== undefined
    ? props.input.onChange({ value: event })
    : form.mutators.clear
}
```

Or maybe this can be done without mutators at all? I would really appreciate your help. Here is a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-from-wreact-dadata-u0skz?fontsize=14) (clearing the field works only on the button click as `onClick={form.mutators.clear}`).

Comment: you forgot to execute it, change `form.mutators.clear` => `form.mutators.clear()` should work.

Answer (score 6):

You can just call `form.change('address', undefined)` at any time that you'd like to clear the value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to add it to the Clear button here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-from-wreact-dadata-u0skz?fontsize=14, but the component doesn't work now (the field doesn't get any value onChange). Also my question is, how can I call this function (or `form.mutators.clear`) when the input is cleared, i. e. when the user deletes what he has typed.

Comment: when the field for clear its part of the object 
is there option ?
i tried but empty all object

Answer (score 0):

All the default callback are handle by the  component. If you want to do a clear with a button click, you can create a custom component and use native callback methods do your thing.

```js
onChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    address:event.target.value
  });
}

onClear = () => {
  this.setState({
    address:''
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <Field name="address">
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.address}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
  </Field>
  <button onClick={this.onClear}>Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I already have a button, which clears the input with `{form.mutators.clear}`. My question is, how can I clear the address field when a user deletes the value from the input.

Comment: You can see the example hear https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-from-wreact-dadata-u0skz?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the react-final-form in your code, it is due to the react-da data,  I have played a lot around your code within 1 day, and checked reset is working with fine with the react-final-form

Just update your render with this code and see reset is working absolutely fine. Yeah! the problem is with react da data. I am not sure about what it does due to less official information for this package.

```js
 <div className="App">
      <h2>Dadata test</h2>
      <Form
        mutators={{
          clear: ([address], state, { changeValue }) => {
            changeValue(state, "address", () => undefined);
          }
        }}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        render={({ form, handleSubmit, pristine, invalid, values, errors }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <Field name="address" component="input" />
              {/* {props => (
                <div>
                  <ReactDadata
                    token="d19c6d0b94e64b21d8168f9659f64f7b8c1acd1f"
                    onChange={event =>
                      props.input.onChange !== undefined
                        ? props.input.onChange({ value: event })
                        : form.mutators.clear
                    }
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </Field> */}
            <button type="submit" disabled={invalid}>
              Submit
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={form.reset}>
              Clear
            </button>
            <Fields names={["address"]}>
              {fieldsState => (
                <pre>{JSON.stringify(fieldsState, undefined, 2)}</pre>
              )}
            </Fields>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
```

Hope it will help you to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply. But I don't need to use `form.reset`. The address field will be only one of the fields in the form. So I need to find a way to clear the value for this only field when the input itself is cleared. You can type `Москва`, select one of the suggestions and then clear the input, to see how it works.

Comment: Basically, I need to integrate `form.mutators.clear` into my onChange function, or find another way to clear address value when the input is cleared.

Comment: Have you tried form.resetFieldState it will reset the value of a particular field. I think it perfect alternative to serving your purpose

Comment: Could you please show an example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-from-wreact-dadata-u0skz?fontsize=14?