# Trying to clear my react-final-form fields but I got empty object values instead

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-final-form, final-form

Here's my scenario, I'm clearing all fields values except for `"retainThisObj"` the rest clear values on initial page load.

My issue is I got empty { } in short my `"retainThisObj"` has been deleted as well. I expected this { retainThisObj }

Here's my code

import { useForm  } from 'react-final-form'

```
  const finalFormAPI = useForm()
  const { retainThisObj, ...restValues } = finalFormAPI.values

 // func to reset field values
  const reset = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).length &&
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((value) => {
        finalFormAPI.change(obj[value], undefined)
      })
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    reset(restValues)   
  }, [restValues])
```

[According to @Erik R. / the author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975830/9215279)

> You can just call form.change('fieldName', undefined) at any time that
> you'd like to clear the value.

What I'm doing is adding a little bit logic to make code efficient.
because If you have lots of fields values you end up like this.

```
form.change('fieldName1', undefined)
form.change('fieldName2', undefined)
form.change('fieldName3', undefined)
form.change('fieldName4', undefined)
and so on..
```

Comment: Might be a problem from
const { retainThisObj, ...restValues } = finalFormAPI.values
I'm not sure what your are trying to do but you can try:
```
const retainThisObj = { retainThisObj, ...finalFormAPI.values }
```

Comment: Hi, can you expand your comment a little bit?  basically I wanted to clear all fields values except for specific field. By the way I already figured it out and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out why, I'm returning `obj[value]` instead just `value`

updated code

```
// func to reset field values
  const reset = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).length &&
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((value) => {
        finalFormAPI.change(value, undefined) 
       // I need the value itself not obj[value] or { name: "value"}
      })
  }
```